# Split string by tokens and cut on condition is true

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I have string like:

```
long_string_part-another_long_string_part some_long_string_part-good still_good already_bad
```

I need to cut them by specific **tokens** `["-"," "]` *(maybe something other in future)* and if totally cuted by all tokens string length are bigger than some value I must cut them to **max allowed length** and add some **replacer**.

After replacing string must be no bigger than max allowed length.

Suppose that **allowed string length** is `10` and **replacer** is `...`.

Expected result is:

```
long_st...-another... some_lo...-good still_good already...
```

How to do it? I think it will be easier implement using regex.
I need to realize this algorithm on **PHP**.

```
$title_parts = preg_split('/[\s\-]+/', $title);
$allowed_word_length = 10;
$replacer = '...';
$is_title_changed = false;
foreach ($title_parts as $index => $title_part) {
    if (mb_strlen($title_part) > $allowed_word_length) {
        $title_parts[$index] = mb_substr($title_part, 0, ($allowed_word_length - mb_strlen($replacer))) . $replacer;
        $is_title_changed = true;
    }
}

if ($is_title_changed) {
    $title = implode(' ',$title_parts);
}
```

[Online example](https://3v4l.org/aukr9)

Issue of my code that token are  in all cases.

Comment: Have you tried anything you can show us?

Comment: @Jackhardcastle of course. There is code example